# Cannot post tweets using TLS 1.2 protocol (Twitterizer2.dll)

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitterizer

We just recently disabled other protocols and enabled TLS 1.2 only. After doing so, the TwitterApp that posts tweets suddenly was not functioning properly. I suspect that the third party library was using SSL or lower versions of tls.

The Application was created using c# and is using Twitterizer2.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have you try to set this in your POST REQUEST?

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Hi @federico, we are using the twitterizer.dll. I believe the request is being done in the library. Do you know any solution how to post to twitter by httprequest in a console application?

Comment: maybe you can check the doc na dAPI of twetter (don't use) their library and do a normal http request